# Convert existing BibTeX to BibJSON

Tags: bibtex

I'm interested in converting my existing bibtex file (generated from Mendeley) into BibJSON format (http://okfnlabs.org/bibjson/), since it would be helpful for me for sharing and other integration purposes. Do you know of any code or script that can take in an existing BibTeX file (*.bib) and create the file in BibJSON format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE 2021:** Citeproc is now integrated with Pandoc. Use something like:

```
pandoc foo.bib -t csljson -o foo.json
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
You can use `pandoc-citeproc`, which is a part of the excellent `pandoc` program, to convert your .bib file to a .json file.

```
pandoc-citeproc --bib2json foo.bib > foo.json
```

But I doubt the output will be exactly what you need, because the specs you have linked seem to go beyond what `pandoc` offers.

Comment: Citeproc is now integrated with Pandoc. Use something like: `pandoc biblio.bib -t csljson -o biblio.json`

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Ruby, you can try  [bibtex-ruby](https://github.com/inukshuk/bibtex-ruby)  module. It has conversions to XML and JSON (`to_json`). Thugh I don't know how close the output is to BibJSON format.

Answer (score 0):

On the project site of BibJSON: http://openbiblio.net/ they refer to https://github.com/zotero/translators which is a

> free, easy-to-use tool to help you collect, organize, cite, and share your research sources.

But the Merge-Request for BibJSON into Zotero got lost. So it does not support export into BibJSON. Maybe CSL Json is a more popular format?