# use bibjson with latex

Tags: bibtex, json

I'm trying to use [bibjson](https://okfnlabs.org/bibjson/) for a LaTeX document. Here are my files:

ecm.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Hello \cite{foo_ref}.

    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
    \bibliography{ecm}
\end{document}
```

ecm.bib

```
@ARTICLE{foo_ref,
    author = {Joe Doe},
    title = {foobar},
    year = {2022}
}
```

pdflatex + bibtex generate a correct pdf document with a bibliography using  `ecm.bib`

Using [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268294/convert-existing-bibtex-to-bibjson) I successfully generated the bibjson:

ecm.json

```
[
  {
    "author": [
      {
        "family": "Doe",
        "given": "Joe"
      }
    ],
    "id": "foo_ref",
    "issued": {
      "date-parts": [
        [
          2022
        ]
      ]
    },
    "title": "foobar",
    "type": "article-journal"
  }
]
```

Now what ?

How do I generate, for example, the file `ecm.bbl` ?

EDIT (to answer moewe's comment)
I want to use json format instead of bib format because there are more tools to work with. Among many others, python has a cool `json` module. So my purpose is to convert bib->json once for all and then forget about the initial bib file.

EDIT (answer) Since nothing seem to exists, I wrote "[jsonbib->bbl](https://github.com/LaurentClaessens/pytex/blob/master/create_bbl.py)" by myself. These functions are quite ad-hoc for [my book](https://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/giulietta.pdf) ([sources](https://github.com/LaurentClaessens/mazhe)), but if it can help someone...

Comment: BibTeX only works with `.bib` input (i.e. the BibTeX file format), it doesn't do `bibjson`. The relatively recent `citeproc-lua` enables you to use CSL styles in LaTeX documents and also supports a JSON-like input format (e.g. https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/blob/main/example/example.json), but I'm not sure if it's the same you have in mind. Apart from that there are a few lesser known BibTeX alternatives (e.g. https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous), but I'm not aware of any that advertises JSON support.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, though, that you say you generated the JSON format from a `.bib` file. In that case wouldn't it be easier to work with the `.bib` directly? (My suggestion would have been to find a library that turns your JSON into a `.bib` file and then use that. With a makefile/`latexmk` approach and a script one could even build that step into the build process so that you can work with the JSON without having to worry about the `.bib` file.)

Comment: @moewe: writing a script json->bbl is, indeed, my last resort idea. My question here is more or less: did someone already did such a script ?

Comment: There is a big difference between JSON -> `.bbl` and JSON -> `.bib`. For `.bbl` you need an output style. For `.bib` you don't (necessarily). As mentioned above, [`citeproc-lua`](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua) lets you use JSON-based files and generates bibliographies with CSL styles. That means you wouldn't be using classical BibTeX, which might be an issue if you need to use a journal template to submit your paper, but if you can live with manual work in that case, that is probably the path of least resistance because everything is there and there are lots of CSL styles.

Comment: You can also use CSL JSON. It is supported by Citeproc-lua, so you can use it directly from LaTeX, and you can use lot of tools to convert BibTeX database to this format (Zotero, [Biblatex-CSL-Converter](https://github.com/fiduswriter/biblatex-csl-converter), [Citation.js](https://citation.js.org/))